# Like button: choice of pictures is not working

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

I put in the *head* tag `<meta property="og:image" content="www.mysite.com/images/logo.png" />`, but the choice of pictures is not working. If <div> in which the facebook button to add `data-image = "http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.png"`, everything works fine. And again, as a "data-image" point directly at multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

The images need to have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1 and the suggested minimum size is 200x200 pixels.

If you add both images in the head tag and are then given the option to choose between them then you will know that both images are allowed.

Can you actually pass an image directly in a like button?

If you look at the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - this doesn't seem to be possible.

I've always specified all my images with og tags in the head e.g.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="www.mysite.com/images/image_1.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="www.mysite.com/images/image_2.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="www.mysite.com/images/image_3.png" />
```